# Show that the set is compact using the definition

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

The set in question is $\{0\}\cup \{1,\frac12,\frac13,\ldots,\frac1n,\ldots\}$ (for $n\in\mathbb N$).

Okay, so for a set to be compact, every open cover of it must be able to be broken down into a finite subcover.

An open subcover of $(-2, 2)$ for instance can be broken down into $(-2,0) \cup (0,2)$. Is my understanding of the definition correct?

Intuitively, I feel like every open set can't possibly be compact. Is this correct. What's the correct approach to putting the logic into mathematical language?

Comment: I think you are missing the gist of the definition of compactness. It amounts to this. For $X$ to be compact, it has to be the case  that if **I give you** a collection of open sets that covers $X$, then you can throw out some of those sets, keeping only a finite number of them, and the collection of the ones you keep **still covers** $X$. You don't get to change any of the sets, just discard some of them if you want. And this has to be true **no matter what collection I give you**, as long as it covers $X$.

Comment: Oh okay, I see. Say I want to prove the set of the singleton one is compact, how would you go about doing that, so I can get a better intuition of what it means to be compact.

Comment: If I give you any collection $\mathscr U$ of open sets covering this singleton space, then there is at least one set, say $U$, in this collection that contains the singleton point (since the collection covers the singleton space). But then we are done--the subcollection $\mathscr V=\{U\}\subset\mathscr U$ is a finite subcollection that also covers the singleton space, right? It's finite because it only contains a single member, namely $U$. The collection I specified could contain who knows how many sets, but I extracted a single set that would do the job.

Comment: Oh okay, I think I got it. Let F = the set above from my question. I say that F is compact. You give me a collection of open sets {G}. I say if it's an open covering of my set F, then my set F MUST be a subset of it. Thus,I can disregard all the other parts of it and keep only the part that contains my set F? Is that an accurate way to prove it? How would one know when a set isn't compact? Say the set (0,1)? Would it not be compact because it has no endpoints? I don't understand. Shouldn't an open covering of (0,1) contain (o,1) and thus can use the same argument?

Comment: Not quite, but you're close. I give you an open covering, you have to throw out all but a finite number of sets in the covering, and what remains is still a covering. The real clincher is: it's not enough to do this for just the one I give you, that might be easy. You have to be able to do this for **every** open cover I give you. (technical point: your set $F$ is a subset of the **union** of the sets in the open cover). Your last question highlights the topic completely, because **you** don't get to specify the open cover, **I** do. [to be continued...]

Comment: [continued] So if I give you the open cover $\{(0,3/4),(1/4,1)\}$ of $(0,1)$, you can easily find a finite sub cover: the cover itself is already finite (contains 2 elements). But what about the cover $\{(0,1-\frac1n):n\in\mathbb N\}$? There is no finite subcover, sot this space is not compact. And yes, it's the endpoints that mess this up here.

Comment: For any noncompact space, you should in theory be able to demonstrate some specific open cover for which there is no finite subcover. That is, every finite subset of that specific given cover fails to cover some part of the space. There will always be some covers that have finite subcovers, you just have to show there is **one** that doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

An open cover of $(-2,2)$ can only be broken down into $(-2,0) \cup (0,2)$ if those two open sets are included in the cover, not to mention that $(-2,0) \cup (0,2)$ fails to cover $(-2,2)$ to begin with (what contains $0$?).

You are right when you say that open sets of $\mathbb R$ are not compact (well the empty set is). To show this, you would have to construct a open cover which can never be reduced to a finite subcover. The simplest open set to look at for this would be $(0,1)$.

To address your main question, is a singleton, say $\{0\}$, compact? What about a set of two real numbers? Three? Some natural number $n$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $A = \{0\} \cup \{\frac 1 n \ | \ n \in \Bbb N\}$.

An open cover of $A$ is a collection of open sets $\{G_{\lambda}  \ | \ \lambda \in I\}$ such that the union of all $G's$, $$\bigcup_{\lambda \in I} G_{\lambda} \supseteq A$$ or in other words the union of $G_{\lambda}$'s covers $A$. Now the reason we use an index $\lambda$ and an index set $I$ is to make the collection $\{G_{\lambda}\}$ "as infinite as you like". That is the number of $G$'s in $\{G_{\lambda}\}$ can be an incredibly large, unfathomable number.

But now, we say the set $A$ is compact if given such an open covering of $A$, $\{G_{\lambda}\}$ contains a finite number of elements $\{G_i \ | \ i = 1,2,..., n\}$ such that the union formed by this finite sub-collection also covers $A$. That is there exists a subcollection $\{G_i \ | \ i = 1,2,..., n\} \subseteq \{G_{\lambda}\}$ such that  $$\bigcup_{i = 1}^n G_i \supseteq A$$

is also true.

Now to prove $A$ is compact, you are required to assume that $\{G_{\lambda}\}$ is an arbitrary open cover of $A$ and then conclude there is a finite number of elements $\{G_1, G_2, ...G_n\}$ in $\{G_{\lambda}\}$ such that $\bigcup_{i = 1}^n G_i$ also covers $A$.

---

Here are the things you need to know to prove that the set $A =  \{0\} \cup \{\frac 1 n \ | \ n \in \Bbb N\}$ is compact.

- $\bigcup_{\lambda \in I} G_{\lambda} \supseteq A$ means for any $a \in A$ there exists $\lambda' \in I$ such that $a \in G_{\lambda'}$. And this is true for every element in $A$, *in particular* $0$.
- A set $G_\lambda$is open if given any $x \in G_\lambda$ there exists an open ball around $x$ which is also contained in $G_\lambda$. That is given any $x \in G_\lambda$ there exists $r \gt 0$ such that $\{y \ | \ |y - x| \lt r\} \subseteq G_\lambda$

Give it a shot. Drop in a comment if you need further help.

Answer (score 0):

Following Ishfaaq, I just want to check if I get his hint since it has been $8$ years now.

Since ${0}$ is the limit of this sequence, it is very essential and powerful to solve the proof. The idea is that although the sequence is infinite approaching $0$, there must ONE set that contains all the infinite elements $\{\frac{1}{n}\}_{n>M}^{\infty}$. Why? Note the open set definition, i.e., the neighborhood of $0$ should be also contained in the set that contains $0$.

We must have $\exists G_i, 0\in G_i$. For this $G_i$, assume that there exists a positive value $b\in G_i$, otherwise, it will not be an open set.

- if $b\ge 1$, then $G_i$ will cover A.
- if $0<b<1$, then let $M=int(\frac{1}{b}+1)$, all elements $\{\frac{1}{n}\}_{n>M}^{\infty} \subseteq G_i$. Then all not-covered elements in A are finite thus we can have finite sets to cover them. Then plus $G_i$, still finite, and cover all elements.

Comment: Since n≤M is finite. and we know each  a is in a set Ga, we just use these finite Ga to cover them. and plus the Gi still finite.

Comment: Thank you! I just modify the answer. change "infinite" to "finite". Serious typos and I didn't even notice it.

Comment: LOL! My fault! Thanks again.